# show that $X^4-4X^2-21$ is solvable by radicals

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, radicals

show that  $$X^4-4X^2-21\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$$ is solvable by radicals.

$\mathrm{Def}$: Let $f(X)\in K[X]$ and let $\Sigma$ be a splitting field for $f(X)$ over $K$. We say $f(X)$ is solvable by radicals if $\exists\;\; M\;$ s.t $M\supseteq \Sigma$  and $M\supseteq K$ is a radical extension.

$\mathrm{Def (2)}$: $L\supset K$ is a rdical extension if there exists a chain of intermediate fields $K=K_{0}\subseteq K_{1}\subseteq K_{2}\subseteq....\subseteq K_{n}=L$ such that $K_{i+1}=K(\alpha_{i})$, where $\alpha_{i}^{r_{i}}\in K_{i}$ for $ \{1,...,n-1\}$

I have problems with understanding these concepts. I suspect just by following the above definitions that  we first need to find a splitting field $\Sigma$ for $f(X)$ over $K$ and then show that  $\Sigma$ is contained in a radical extension $L\supseteq K$.

Let $u=x^2$ then we get $u^2-4u-21=0$ with roots $x_{1}=-3$ and $x_{2}=7$

So the original equation splits in linear factors

$X^4-4X^2-21=(x-\sqrt{7})(x+\sqrt{7})(x-i\sqrt{3})(x+i\sqrt{3})$

Hence the splitting field $\Sigma=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{3},\sqrt{7})$
but as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{7})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{7})$ we can simplify the splitting field to 
 $\Sigma=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{7})$

What should I do next? How to create (find) $M$ that will contain $\Sigma$? And how to show that $M\supseteq \mathbb{Q}$ is radical then? Any help appreciated.

Comment: You have already done all the hard work. The chain of intermediate fields you need is simply $K_0={\mathbb Q}, K_1=K_0(i), K_2=K_1(\sqrt{3}), K_3=K_2(\sqrt{7})$.

Comment: Ah okay, so which field is $M$. It should contain $\Sigma$. Is is $\mathbb{C}$? Maybe I still don't get it by in what extension does the splitting field lie??

Comment: $M$ is the last and largest one of them, $K_3={\mathbb Q}(i,\sqrt{3},\sqrt{7})$.

Comment: By the way, there is a typo in your definition of radical extension. It should be ${\alpha_i}^{r_i} \in K_{i}$.

Comment: I am not quite sure, but I believe the splitting field of the polynomial should be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7},i \sqrt{3})$ and I believe this to be different from $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7},i ,\sqrt{3})$, but haven't thought about it enough. This is, of course, not so important, as both are radical extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: Thank you! I have fixed the typo.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch: How will you obtain $\sqrt{3}$ from your field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7},i\sqrt{3})$?

Comment: @HeidiE : There is no need to obtain $\sqrt{3}$ from $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7},i\sqrt{3})$. In fact, if you could do this, then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7},i\sqrt{3})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{7},\sqrt{3})$ would be identical (which they are not). In fact, I was trying to make the point that the actual splitting field of your polynomial is smaller than $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{7},\sqrt{3})$, namely $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7},i\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch: Yes of course! I somehow overlooked (or was just a bit sloppy) that $\sqrt{3}$ is not one of the roots instead of $\sqrt{3}i$. Then the splitting field you suggested is absolutely sufficient. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

In your description you actually give a solution in radicals, so you don't need any Galois theory to show that your equation is solvable in radicals.

Comment: The problem is taken from my course book in Galois theory.

Comment: @HeidiE I don't see why this is relevant. A solution in radicals is proof that the equation is solvable in radicals.